# Conditionals, second conditional

Tags: conditionals

Imagine that I am speaking to a friend who is meeting the president tomorrow.
Would it be correct if I said to him:

> If I met the president tomorrow, I wouldn't sleep this night.

Should I say "If I met the president tomorrow..." or "If I would meet the president tomorrow..."?

Answer (score 1):

"Met" is past tense. But "tomorrow" means it's in the future. So no, that doesn't make sense. You should use future tense if it's tomorrow. As it's a conditional, then you'd use a future conditional. "If I was going to meet the president tomorrow, I wouldn't sleep tonight."

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your answer! Is English your mother language?

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou Yes.

Comment: Hi! I am very impressed with your answer! Well done!

Answer (score -1):

This is the second conditional and refers to imaginary events in the future that have a low probability of occurring.

A better, more idiomatic, form of your sentence = If I were to meet the president tomorrow, I wouldn't be able to sleep tonight.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct to say "if I would meet her tomorrow...", "If I met her tomorrow...", "If I was meeting her tomorrow..."?

Comment: If I met her tomorrow = correct......................as for the others, they are incorrect ...............If I were to meet her tomorrow; if I were meeting her tomorrow.

Comment: "If I were to meet..." is incorrect? But earlier you wrote it was a better and more idiomatic form. I don't understand you.

Comment: No. I put my corrections in place of your mistakes. So,.If I were to meet her tomorrow.................and.............. if I were meeting her tomorrow................. are both correct

Comment: Ok, I got it. And "If I met her tomorrow..." is also grammatically correct, isn't it?

Comment: If I met her tomorrow = correct.................2nd cond.